ASP.NET Core MVC return 405 error becomes 404
I created my AuthorizeSessionAttribute to handle permission in my web application. The problem is when I do not authorize access to an API and I do this:
public class AuthorizeSessionAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter 
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (AuthorizeCore(context)) 
        {
            await next();
        }
        else 
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }

    protected bool AuthorizeCore(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Some not interesting code
    }

    protected void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Some not interesting code

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
        }

        context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }));
    }
}

This is my Program.cs file:
public class Program
{
    const string AppCors = "_AppCors";
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<BaseDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient
        );
#endif

        builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = false; });

        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<INominatimWebInterface, NominatimWebInterface>();

        builder.Services.AddSession(options => { options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        builder.Services.AddMvc(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            })
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
            .AddRazorOptions(options => {
                options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
                options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/{0}.cshtml");
            })
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
        builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        WebApplication app = builder.Build();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
        };

        app.UseCors(AppCors);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?status={0}");

        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.Run();
    }
}

I tried also with Unauthorized but, in browser I can see that the response is always 404.
What could be the problem? I have no more information. If I have permission I get the code 200 as a response.

And what is the problem?

Can you post a Minimal reproducible example?

did you mean to say 405 becomes 401 (Unauthrorized)? or actually 404 (not found)

the answer of this question can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498723/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core

Are you inheriting the AuthorizeAttribute or you have some specific middleware which will handle the 500 error and it doesn't contain the specific page.  All in all ,without the codes, we don't know the reason.

@Ruslan I want to response with 405 but it becomes 404. I tried to response with 401 but it becomes always 404.

@GeorgeKarlinzer I simply created a custom attribute that inherits from IAsyncActionFilter. I used it on any Controller in my MVC application. I'll try to update example with more code.

The code you have shared will not even build well. The HandleUnauthorizedRequest method is void, but you still return the result, actually, you should use the context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed); instead.
More details, you could refer to below example:
1.Filter:
public class AuthorizeSessionAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (AuthorizeCore(context))
        {
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }

    protected bool AuthorizeCore(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Some not interesting code
        return false;
    }

    protected void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Some not interesting code


        context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);

    }
}

2.Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthorizeSessionAttribute>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.AddService<AuthorizeSessionAttribute>();
});

Result:
Result:


Sorry, my mistake. Copy-Paste errors. Now I corrected my code. I also forgot about the inheritance from the Attribute class.

Your code still work well at my side,  you need provide the more details information like controller, program.cs to let us test it,

I have no middlewares and nothing interesting in program.cs. I use my attribute in this way: [AuthorizeSession(Permission.LOG)] public class LogController { ... }

I still couldn't reproduce the issue, I guess you have some other filter, please share a reproduce example with the whole codes.

I added also the Program.cs file

I found. The problem is this line: app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?status={0}");. It works fine with normal post and get calls, but with ajax cause a 404 error.

I solved changing two parts of code. The first is the middleware:
// app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?status={0}");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");

The second part is the action of ErrorController:
[Route("Error/{status}")] // <-- New part
public IActionResult Index(string status) {
    return View(model: status);
}

In this way also Ajax works fine.
